# Why do I get an HttpException from VirtualPathUtility ToAbsolute with some paths?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, system.web, httpexception

I'm trying to use [`VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150160%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to resolve app-relative paths, such as `~/MyPage.aspx`, to application-absolute paths, such as `/MySite/MyApp/MyPage.aspx`. However, with some paths, I receive an `HttpException` saying that my path is "not a valid virtual path". Examples:

```
// This works:
var abs1 = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/MyPage.aspx#anchor");

// This errors:
var abs2 = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/MyPage.aspx?key=value");
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because you're using .NET 3.5, you're using the `2.0` `System.Web` assembly, which has the defect that `?` is considered an illegal path character by this method. This is mentioned in the community comments on the [version-specific MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150160%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

By disassembling, it can be seen that the call ends up in the (`internal`) `VirtualPath.Create`, which has:

```
  else if (VirtualPath.ContainsIllegalVirtualPathChars(virtualPath))
  {
    throw new HttpException(System.Web.SR.GetString("Invalid_vpath", new object[1]
    {
      (object) virtualPath
    }));
  }
```

which references

```
private static char[] s_illegalVirtualPathChars = new char[4]
{
  ':',
  '?',
  '*',
  char.MinValue
};
```

Some of these can reasonably be regarded as bad characters for a path, but `?` shouldn't really be so rejected.

Disassembly of the `4.0` `System.Web` shows that `VirtualPath.Create` has been rewritten to be more discerning.

[This web.archive capture of a now-defunct blogs.msdn post](http://web.archive.org/web/20100330050530/http://blogs.msdn.com/dmitryr/archive/2006/02/21/536552.aspx) shows one of the earliest mentions of this problem. The MS employee responds:

> Sunday, February 26, 2006 11:49 PM by DmitryR Exception on `~/path?qs`
>   is a bug that I'll need to fix...
>
> The easiest fix is to save/restore query string in
>   `ResolveAppRelativeLinkToUrl` around the call to
>   `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`.
>
> A workaround is to use fully qualified UTLs instead of "~/...".
>
> Thanks,
>
> Dmitry

where `ResolveAppRelativeLinkToUrl` refers to the reporter's code's method name.

Another workaround would be to replace `?` with a safe token before the call to `VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute`, and reverse the replacement afterwards:

```
public static string SafeToAbsolute(string path)
{
    var madeSafe = path.Replace("?", "UNLIKELY_TOKEN");
    var absolute = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(madeSafe);
    var restored = absolute.Replace("UNLIKELY_TOKEN", "?");
    return restored;
}
```

choosing a suitably unlikely token for your application.

Comment: @GrantThomas I honestly can't tell if you're being tongue-in-cheek or not; if you're not, I refer you to [What is this “answer your own question” jazz?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132886)