# System.Web.HttpException: '<url with queystring>' is not a vaid path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following helper method:

```
    public static String ResolveUrl(String url)
    {
        url = url.Trim();
        if (!(url[0] == '~')) return url;
        try
        {
            if (VirtualPathUtility.IsAppRelative(url)) return VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(url);
            return url;
        }
        catch (HttpException)
        {
            return url;
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it raises an exception if the provided URL contains a querystring, eg. `~/showcase/View.aspx?id=10783`.

Stack trace:

```
System.Web.HttpException was caught
  Message='~/showcase/View.aspx?id=10783' is not a valid virtual path.
  Source=System.Web
    ErrorCode=-2147467259
    StackTrace:
         at System.Web.VirtualPath.Create(String virtualPath, VirtualPathOptions options)
         at System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.IsAppRelative(String virtualPath)
         at Ctf.Common.ResolveUrl(String url) in [redacted]Common.cs:line 359
    InnerException:
```

What's the problem here? Does `VirtualPathUtility` just not support querystring URLs?

Edit: I should add that the helper is perfectly fine with other app-relative URLs as long as there isn't a querystring on them.

Edit2: I've made a hack workaround by removing the querystring from the URL before calling the VirtualPathUtility methods, then gluing it back on at the end. I'd rather avoid this if possible.

Comment: does it perhaps expect an absolute url, and is rejecting yours since it doesn't have `http://example.com/~....`?

Comment: The whole point of `VirtualPathUtility.IsAppRelative` is to detect whether the URL is an app-relative path, ie. begins with `~/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.5 and below, then you are right, `VirtualPathUtility` will not accept a query string as a valid part of a virtual path for those methods. You'll have to trim off the query string and re-append it on your absolute URL. Check out this excellent question / answer [Why do I get an HttpException from VirtualPathUtility ToAbsolute with some paths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360419/why-do-i-get-an-httpexception-from-virtualpathutility-toabsolute-with-some-paths).